# localhost server not responding for middleman development environment

Tags: middleman

I am running Mountain Lion, none RVM managed.

I have attempted:

```
middleman server -p 4567 -e development

middleman server
```

and

```
bundle exec middleman server
```

I've tried various combinations with templates, removed the install and started over several times.

Everything seems to run just find and middleman is standing watch, etc. I then navigate to `http://localhost:4567/` (when applicable) and the browser always says that it cannot connect to the server "localhost"

the problem persists across two environments with dropbox sinking the source files between the two. Maybe I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out any other steps from the docs and I've tried to connect to the official user forum but repeated "resends" of the confirmation e-mail don't work for two different accounts. Yah, it's been one of those development days...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for some reason localhost is getting grabbed up on my computer. switching to 0.0.0.0:4500 solves it.